# Disable excel build in Ribbon button find (FindDialogExcel)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I want to disable find button (Home-->find & select-->find) only in sheet1 but its enable on other sheets.

Is it possible to disable a build in ribbon button without customize ribbon?

Comment: Even if that's possible, can't users open click the ribbon button and then switch to that sheet? Or simply click `Ctrl+F`? How are you going to prevent that?

Comment: i use this vba code to prevent ctrl+f

Comment: Sub find()
'
' find Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f
'
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Comment: if it possible with c# code access build in  ribbon control?